# I made a bit unorthodox calculator in c++, how to make it better?

Tags: c++, calculator

I made a calculator in C++ by using name: and goto name; etc. and i read that it isn't advisable. What should i do instead, and why isn't it good? Would also be nice for a few tips on how else i could have improved my code, as I am not completely satisfied with how you i.e choose arithmetic expression.

```
Code:
    #include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

                    double nr1, nr2, sum;
                    int tegn, y, res1;
        nr1=0;
        nr2=0;
        tegn=0;
        sum=0;
        res1=0;
        y=1;
restart:
cout<<"Enter a number for your preferred arithmetic expression."<<endl<<"Press 1 for addition"<<endl;
cout<<"Press 2 for subtraction"<<endl<<"Press 3 for division"<<endl<<"Press 4 for multiplication"<<endl;
cin>>tegn;
switch(tegn)
{
case 1:
    goto addition;
break;
case 2:
    goto subtraction;
break;
case 3:
    goto division;
break;
case 4:
    goto multiplication;
break;
default:
    cout<<"Wrong button pressed, restarting"<<endl;
    goto restart;
    break;
}
addition:
cout<<"Enter your first number, please"<<endl;
cin>>nr1;
cout<<"Now, enter you second number, please"<<endl<<endl;
cin>>nr2;
    sum=nr1+nr2;
cout<<nr1<<" + "<<nr2<<" = "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Enter y(yes) or n(no) to restart"<<endl;
cin>>res1;
    if (res1==y) {
        goto restart;
    }
    else {
        goto end;
    }
subtraction:
    cout<<"Enter your first number, please"<<endl;
cin>>nr1;
cout<<"Now, enter you second number, please"<<endl<<endl;
cin>>nr2;
    sum=nr1-nr2;
cout<<nr1<<" - "<<nr2<<" = "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Enter y(yes) or n(no) to restart"<<endl;
cin>>res1;
    if (res1==y) {
        goto restart;
    }
    else {
        goto end;
    }
division:
    cout<<"Enter your first number, please"<<endl;
cin>>nr1;
cout<<"Now, enter you second number, please"<<endl<<endl;
cin>>nr2;
    sum=nr1/nr2;
cout<<nr1<<" :"<<nr2<<" = "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Enter y(yes) or n(no) to restart"<<endl;
cin>>res1;
    if (res1==y) {
        goto restart;
    }
    else {
        goto end;
    }
multiplication:
    cout<<"Enter your first number, please"<<endl;
cin>>nr1;
cout<<"Now, enter you second number, please"<<endl<<endl;
cin>>nr2;
    sum=nr1*nr2;
cout<<nr1<<" * "<<nr2<<" = "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Enter y(yes) or n(no) to restart"<<endl;
cin>>res1;
    if (res1==y) {
        goto restart;
    }
    else {
        goto end;
    }
end:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: F.Y.I Tegn means sign or character in Norwegian

Comment: Working code should be posted to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is known as unstructured programming.  It is honestly fine at this scale, but it is very "write only" after a bit of time, and gets cumbersome as programs get larger.

Structured programming involves loops, subprocedures and functions.  Object oriented programming involves creating new objects that abstract concepts and communication protocols.  Event based is another, as is monadic, functional, coroutine state machine, etc.

However, usually the next step after this is learning how to write functions or subprocedures.  You take a bit of code, define inputs and outputs, and put it in a function.  Usually you can clear out every goto doing this.  Create a central loop that dispatches to helper functions.  Define the state that persists between loop carefully.

This will take practice.  Good luck.